# how to write a diamond shape only with nested for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops

Alright so I'm new to for nested loops and having a hard time understanding them.

The prompt:

Write a program that prints the shape shown below. You may use output statements that print either a single asterisk (*) or a single blank. Maximize your use of repetition (with nested for structures) and minimize the number of output statements.

```
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
    ***********
     *********
      *******
```

What I have so far:

```
 for (int row = 7; row <= 13; row = row + 2){
     for (int col = 1; col <= row; col++)
         cout << '*';
     cout << '\n';
 }



 for ( int row = 12; row >= 7; row = row - 2) {
     for ( int col = 1; col <= row; col++ )
         cout << '*';
     cout << '\n';
 }
```

I can't figure out the spacing? The spaces go down by one for the first three lines and up by one for the next three lines. How should I add them in?

Comment: I don't see a diamond.

Comment: Okay, how about now?

Comment: @RockySingh - the shape's visible, but that's _not_ a diamond.

Comment: @enhzflep Its not spouse to be a diamond, it's square like diamond.

Comment: Please ask genuine questions instead of posting your homework problems here on SO.

Comment: @RockySingh - er, ah, um - so the title is wrong then. Try to be a little more careful and precise. You're not painting impressionist landscapes here, you're programming a computer - details are important in this field.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question and any answers are unique to your situation and are unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: @KubaOber: That's exactly why I wrote the answer in the generalized  way. "Even though this explanation uses a specific assignment as the example it is a general approach and, if learned, it should help you and others with this kind of programming problems."

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. The hardest part with this kind of assignments is to figure out the 'rule' or the formula for the amount of blanks and amount of stars in each row based on the index of the row. Once you have that figured out translating that into a program is the easier part.

EDIT: Even though this explanation uses a specific assignment as the example it is a general approach and, if learned, it should help you and others with this kind of programming problems.

You can make it easier by marking the rows with their index

```
0      *******
1     *********
2    ***********
3   *************
4    ***********
5     *********
6      *******
```

And then make an input - output table

```
row  blanks *s
0    6       7
1    5       9
2    4      11
3    3      13
4    4      11
5    5       9
6    6       7
```

This table can be expanded (generalized) to any number of rows from `1` to `N` (`N>=1`), but it's really for `N>=3` that it starts to make sense. Sometimes a decision should be made how **even** and **odd** values for `N` are handled, but that is usually possible to figure out from the samples that you are provided.
In your example the number of rows is 7 so `N=7`.

By knowing your input `N` you can start generalizing the above table by replacing values with calculations (as functions of `N`)

```
N=7

row  blanks  *s
0    N-1     N+0
1    N-2     N+2
2    N-3     N+4
3    N-4     N+6
4    N-3     N+4
5    N-2     N+2
6    N-1     N+0
```

At this point if you can't determine a single formula for all rows yet just introduce new helper variables. We can see that in the top half of the table we see increasing correction values (+0, +2, +4, +6) and in the bottom half of the table we see decreasing correction values (+6, +4, +2, +0). So let's introduce a helper variable that will help us with the bottom half of the table (similar to how the `row` index helps us with the top half). I will call this variable `help1`.

```
N=7

row  help1  blanks  *s
0    6      N-1     N+0
1    5      N-2     N+2
2    4      N-3     N+4
3    3      N-4     N+6
4    2      N-3     N+4
5    1      N-2     N+2
6    0      N-1     N+0
```

At this point if the pattern is still too hard to generalize you could just split the problem in 2 cases and use an `if {} else {}` statement in your program. One for the top half of the table (`if` part) and one for the bottom half (`else` part). However, if you look closely at the relation between `row` and `help1` variables and the correction values for blanks and asterisks you can see that they follow a pattern. There is a linear relation between them. You can see that you always need to subtract or add the **smaller** value of `row` and `help1` to get the desired number of blanks or asterisks for a given row. So let's introduce a new helper for the smaller value also called minimum or `min` for short.

```
row  help1  min  blanks  *s
0    6      0    N-1     N+0
1    5      1    N-2     N+2
2    4      2    N-3     N+4
3    3      3    N-4     N+6
4    2      2    N-3     N+4
5    1      1    N-2     N+2
6    0      0    N-1     N+0
```

And now let's use the `min` helper variable to update the last 2 columns of the table as well.

```
row  help1  min  blanks     *s
0    6      0    N-(min+1)  N+2*min
1    5      1    N-(min+1)  N+2*min
2    4      2    N-(min+1)  N+2*min
3    3      3    N-(min+1)  N+2*min
4    2      2    N-(min+1)  N+2*min
5    1      1    N-(min+1)  N+2*min
6    0      0    N-(min+1)  N+2*min
```

And the table is fully generalized.

The hint from the assignment is to use nested structures (nested loops). The general idea would be to use an outer loop to iterate over the rows from `0` to `N-1` and an inner loop (or two) to print the required amount of blanks and asterisks for the current row.

Now it's up to you to figure out the loop conditions and steps/increments and the calculations of the helper variables `help1` and `min`.

Comment: Downvoters, please elaborate, how should I improve my answer?

Comment: I didn't vote, but it seems clear and plainly obvious that your is not a solution to the problem. Certainly, it offers some steps towards a solution, but aside from the 'pics', it's really nothing more than a comment.

Comment: @enhzflep I actually agree with Ma3x who is trying to providing a clue but not actually solving it for him as this seems a homework assignment. There is nothing written anywhere that you have to provide a working solutions in SO. These questions would have many answers that take them to the right direction.

Comment: Yes, just to be clear, I decided to give him some clues instead of posting the solution because this is clearly an assignment. I also think that an answer that is nothing more than a comment is still more than a troll comment. Now, if the question does not belong to SO, that is another story and the question itself should be removed but that has nothing to do with the comment/answer.

Comment: @bhantol - if you read (again?) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer you'll see #4 is labelled "Answer the question" - I agree that answers that point the asker in the right direction are mentioned explicitly and are not disallowed. However, those are low-quality answers and ones likely to attract down-votes. Another potential reason is that helping students with homework is looked down upon when  little effort has been shown to solve it. Again, I did not vote - whoever did has been silent and all I've tried to do is provide assistance in understanding why some would downvote it..(cont)

Comment: I actually think the suggestions given are good ones. They're exactly what I'd done already and are the best method I know of to devise a formula for calculating the number of spaces and stars required in each row.

Comment: @enhzflep You should read how-to-answer fully `Answer the question` section. When it says `Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful,` is what I am implying. A full correct answer would be that code snippet that you and I and Ma3x can provide but would defeat the purpose. Today this is the 3rd I noticed which are homework like and I have been asking the questions to provide hint but the comment section does not allow what Ma3x did. I guess I have a bit lenient version of those rules.

Comment: @bhantol - Er, I did. That's why I both left a link to the page and mentioned the same point. ;) Course it's homework and with so little done, I'm not inclined to offer anything. Kids these days are spoiled. When I started in the field, neither linux nor Internet Explorer had even come out, and a 64 bit machine (with an _enormous_ 1gig of memory) cost as much as a fairly nice car. 90% of the research we did was in libraries, with books. To be clear - I don't have a problem with Ma3x's solution - I do have a reasonable feel for what will get hit with the downvote hammer though, and why.

Comment: @Ma3x - What an awesome edit, addition and explanation. Alas, I have but one vote. Time & effort to explain the process of solving the problem, rather than simply providing a solution is becoming increasingly rare and is a valuable commodity. Bravo!

Comment: @enhzflep: Thanks! And just to be clear, I agree with you and the rules. That's also why I was expecting some criticism when I decided to post as an answer. I have to admit that my first comment was also a bit of a bait for the downvoter (sorry you decided to answer it, but I am glad we had this short convo), because I already knew exactly how I was gonna improve it. However, I had to wait just in case that the question was getting deleted.

Comment: @Ma3x Thank you!!